# Java : My error is a cannot find symbol in run method for Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Battle extends Thread{

   public Battle(Object instructor1, Object instructor2){

}

public void run(){

  while ((instructor1.getCurrentHP() > 0) || (instructor2.getCurrentHP() > 0)){ //ERROR HERE
     System.out.print(2);
  }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
   Instructor instructor1 = new Instructor("Big Omar Latif", 999, 145, 180, 4000);
   Instructor instructor2 = new Instructor("Small Ali Raza", 400, 185, 230, 1200);
   Battle x = new Battle(instructor1, instructor2);

   x.start();

} 


}
```

'''
So heres my code. I have 2 instructors fighting each other and there will be mulitple rounds for them.
I want a battle(round) to be threaded.
Now when i run this, i get a symbol not found error for the while loop for the instructor1 and instructor2. Im assuming my understanding for the run() method isnt clear. Can you help me figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare Object instructor1, Object instructor2 as a global variable and initialize them in constructor in order for them to access on different methods.

```
  public class Battle extends Thread{

    private Object instructor1;
    private Object instructor2;

      public Battle(Object instructor1, Object instructor2){
         this.instructor1=instructor1;
         this.instructor2=instructor2;
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this worked!! But right now the probelm is that my class methods are not running. If i    System.out.print(instructor1); it works. but if i   System.out.print(instructor1.getCurrentHP()); it says symbol not found

Comment: Java does not have global variables, and these are instance variables (the opposite of globals). They should certainly be typed `Instructor` as well.

Comment: Adding on, When i print both statements in the main function, it prints both.